# Easy solution to resize, crop and print a passport photo of 35x45mm?

Tags: photos

What is a simple solution, and preferably free, for cropping and printing a photo to 35x45?

Somethink that would ease the generation of a photo that does match:
http://www.direct.gov.uk/prod_consum_dg/groups/dg_digitalassets/@dg/@en/@motor/documents/digitalasset/dg_078280.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a web tool that does it - it's for US passports, but presumably the size guidelines are similar or the same for the UK

http://travel.state.gov/_res/flash/cropper/FIG_cropper.html#

Answer (score 0):

I use Preview and a ruler. The inspector window and crop tool will get you close to the size needed.

Then print out the picture and use the ruler to measure your results on paper. You can then adjust the scaling up or down as needed if you didn't nail it the first time. Once you have the % dialed in, print as many copies as you need.